# How to find the name/title of a UIImage in swift?

Tags: swift, uiimage

please help to find out the image name which is stored in Photo Library of a Phone.

This is the code I have tried:

```
    let x = self.imageView.accessibilityLabel
    println(x)
```

Comment: You're obviously loading the image from somewhere, so why not get the name then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that functionality is not built into `UIImage` because images are not always loaded from files. However, you could create a custom `UIImageView` subclass to fit your needs.

Comment: can you please help me to create local folder to store images and retrieve images from that folder

Comment: I can; but my answer will be in Objective-C because I haven't worked seriously with Swift yet.  Will that be acceptable?

Comment: No problem I understand.  Since you have a new question and you have already marked this one as closed I would recommend creating a new SO question so it will get the proper attention.

Comment: @RaviG   why you want to create local folder??? xcode project from where you work just simply copy images(which you want to use in your project)